# Change variable value from an input in Python

Tags: python, variables, input

I'm wondering how to change a variable from a user input.. For example

```
new = raw_input("enter a new variable for x:")
x = new
```

Comment: Change a variable? You are assigning the value from `new` into the variable called `x`, which works, but your question is not clear at all.

Comment: Change a variable how? Changing type? Location of storage? Type of storage? This is pretty vague.

Comment: @Jordan The correct manner to express is that ``x = new`` assigns the object **new** whose identifier is ``new`` to the other identifier ``x`` . Doing that, the assignement between ``new`` and the object isn't lost or destroyed. It simply means that after the assignement ``x = new`` , the object initialy assigned only to ``new`` has now two identifiers : ``x`` and still ``new``. Identifiers are like etiquettes. If you won't see the things like that instead of using this confusing word 'variable' in Python, you'll have always problems to understand many phenomenons in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me as if what you are doing would work, though it could be simplified.

```
x=raw_input("New value for x: ")
```

Should change the value of `x` to the input.

Comment: would it recognize X as a variable and save it however? like if I had x = 2, x=raw_input("New Value:") "3".. x=3.. Like if X was already defined as a variable before the new value was input, would it change it completely?

Comment: @JordanChillMcgeeLudgate It should... Have you tried it?

Comment: No, I'm in class right now. I'll try it when I get home. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks, Just tried it. It worked! For anyone whos reading this and wondering the same thing, just remember if your changing a variable in a function, declare your variable as a global!

Comment: @Jordan In case of ``x = 2 ; x=raw_input("New Value:") ; x = 3`` , x is not defined as a variable before the input is done. What do you cal x by the way when you say that ? The object ? The identifier ? - The story is that before the input, ``x`` is an identifier that is sticked to the integer object 2, then sticked to the string object entered by the input, then sticked to the integer object 3, and that's all. That's not the set of bits designated by the identifier that is modified, it's the identifier which is unsticked and sticked elsewhere in the memory. Point